# Google ads api field asset.name is empty in ad_group_ad_asset_view with type YOUTUBE_VIDEO

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm querying Google Ads Api via google/apiclient:2.0 in PHP using this GAQL:

```
SELECT asset.final_urls, asset.name, asset.type, asset.id
FROM ad_group_ad_asset_view
WHERE segments.date = '$date'
```

But all the type `YOUTUBE_VIDEO` result had an empty `asset.name`. When I query from the hub, the Asset name is not empty. What should I do to get the right asset name for `YOUTUBE_VIDEO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that `YOUTUBE_VIDEO` asset should get aseet name from `asset.youtube_video_asset.youtube_video_title`